# else if not working in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I want to display the selected picture in the picture box. Following is the code:

```
Private Sub Drive1_Change()
Dir1.Path = Drive1.Drive
End Sub

Private Sub Dir1_Change()
File1.Path = Dir1.Path
End Sub

Private Sub File1_Click()
On Error GoTo lab
lab:
If Err.Number = 481 Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a valid Picture")
Else
    If Err.Number = 68 Then
        MsgBox ("Device not ready")
    End If
End If
Resume Next
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(File1.Path + "\" + File1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Case 481 works perfectly fine but the second case, error 68 does not work at all. It shows run time error 68. Following is the output:

[image]

Please let me know about the errors in the above code.

Comment: need more info. which line is throwing the error? if one inside File1_Click your error managing is not effective since it lets you get at 'Picture1.Picture...' in any case

Comment: it would be elseif written together

Comment: If this is VB6, why the VBA tag? VBA and VB6 are NOT the same, even though they share (some) functionality. Which is it? If it's VB6 you want to change the tag so that you can be sure the right people see this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you normally put your error handler *before* the code which may be throwing the error?  I'm not able to replicate this with a simple case on my own, but the structure of this code seems suspect.  You also have a `Resume Next` without a loop.  Try this instead:

```
Private Sub File1_Click()
On Error GoTo lab
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(File1.Path + "\" + File1.FileName)
Exit Sub

lab:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 481 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a valid Picture")
    Case 68 Then
        MsgBox ("Device not ready")
End Select

End Sub
```

Sounds like you may need additional error handlers in your other procedures, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Dir1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    File1.Path = Dir1.Path
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 68
            Msgbox ("Device not ready")
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Error " & Err.NUmber) '# Modify as needed...
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Drive1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dir1.Path = Drive1.Drive
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 68
            Msgbox ("Device not ready")
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Error " & Err.NUmber) '# Modify as needed...
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Dir1.Path = Drive1.Drive

Comment: That would've been helpful to know in your original question, of course... You don't have *any* error handling in that procedure. Your error handler is local only to the `File1_Click` event procedure.

Comment: hmm... My mistake... I get it know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I revised the answer with local error handler in each procedure.